# Join Pyspark Dataframes where two lists share a value

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes of the form

```
df1 = 
+------+---------+
|group1|  members|
+------+---------+
|     1|[a, b, c]|
|     2|[d, e, f]|
|     3|[g, h, i]|
+------+---------+

df2 = 
+------+---------+
|group2|  members|
+------+---------+
|     4|[s, t, d]|
|     5|[u, v, w]|
|     6|[x, y, b]|
+------+---------+
```

I would like to perform a join on these dataframes based on a condition when the members lists share a common value. For example, `group2` would map onto `df1` as:

```
+------+---------+------+
|group1|  members|group2|
+------+---------+------+
|     1|[a, b, c]|     6|
|     2|[d, e, f]|     4|
|     3|[g, h, i]|      |
+------+---------+------+
```

Is there an efficient method for this? At the moment I am just looping through the rows of `df2` and using `f.array_intersect()` to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a left join, the join condition is to use the `size` function to determine that the intersection of df1 and df2 is greater than 0.

```
df2 = df2.toDF('group2', 'members2')
df = df1.join(df2, F.size(F.array_intersect(df1.members, df2.members2)) > 0, 'left').drop('members2')
df.show(truncate=False)
```